# How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(t+\frac1t)}}{\sqrt t} dt$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, closed-form, gaussian-integral

This is a problem given in my homework . I have to find the integral$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(t+\frac{1}{t})}}{\sqrt t}dt$$

I am trying to use integral representation of the gamma function but I was not able to get it in the region of convergence i.e. $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}$ is clearly $\Gamma (\frac{1}{2})$ but the second factor is causing a problem. Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint.** Make the change of variable $t=x^2$ to obtain
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(t+\frac{1}{t})}}{\sqrt t}dt=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{ -x^2-1/x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -x^2-1/x^2}dx
$$
You may then recall that, for any integrable function $f$, we have

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{s}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x, \quad s>0. \tag1
> $$

Apply it to $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, you get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-s/x)^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}, \quad s>0. \tag2
$$

Thus

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2-s^2/x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{-2s}\tag3
$$ then put $s=1$ to obtain your integral.

Comment: great answer thanks a lot

Comment: I hadn't seen the formula in the gray bar, and was computing the same thing in a messier way. This is cleaner. It is nice to know that formula. (+1)